# CMSampleBuffer duplicate audio channel

Tags: ios, avfoundation, core-audio, cmsamplebuffer

Given a mono audio CMSampleBuffer with one channel, how do I create a new CMSampleBuffer which has two channels and whose other channel audio samples are duplicate of the other channel? In other words, I need to create stereo from mono audio.

Comment: do you want interleaved or non-interleaved stereo?

Comment: non-interleaved would also do

Comment: Did you ever find a method to do this?